# Stop Hover effect of an item using JQUERY

Tags: jquery, css, hover

I have some `div` elements and each of them have a `hover` effect applied by CSS. But I don't always want this hover effect; it should only activate under specific conditions.

Now, how can I disable those `hover` effects using jQuery when my conditions are satisfied? What is the code for disabling `hover`?  I don't have access to CSS files.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just use the [jQuery `hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) instead of the CSS one.

E.g. instead of such CSS:

```
#Div1:hover { background-color: yellow; }
```

Have this jQuery:

```
$("#Div1").hover(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
}, function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "");
});
```

Same effect, and you control the JS code and can have conditions.
Live test case: http://jsfiddle.net/THXuc/

Comment: Thanks mate. But I have no access to CSS files.

Comment: @abdullah, you dont neet to have access to css files, `.css()` appends whatever is written to your css

Comment: Yep, what ian said - CSS files are not relevant for jQuery. :)

Answer (score 2):

you can do this by using

```
<script>
$("someDiv").hover(function(event) {
//apply some conditions if yes
  event.preventDefault();
else
return true;
});
</script>
```

Hope this will work for you....

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could apply a different class to the `div`(s) in question, using jquery `.hover()`. On mousein, apply the class and on mouseout, remove it.